# What set of bits is compatible with a Bosch Uneo (SDS-Quick)?

Tags: drill, bits

I've tried searching for at least an hour, but I'm finding very few resources and the compatibility situation is very confusing and frustrating.  Most things seem to be compatible with SDS-Max/Plus, instead.

I'm wanting to buy a variety set of bits for a Bosch Uneo, which uses SDS-Quick.  I've not been able to find an adapter from SDS-Quick to a normal chuck, so unfortunately that limits my choices.

The only things that I'm sure are SDS-Quick compatible are [here](https://www.bosch-do-it.com/gb/en/diy/accessories/accessories-for-rotary-hammers-200516.jsp).  However, that's a very limited set of bits.  Is there really no variety set of 50-100 bits available?

I've tried looking through Amazon reviews, but there's a lot of conflicting reviews, and the product information is unhelpful.

Comment: No, I'm having a hard time knowing what's compatible with my drill in the first place.  I have no problem searching for the best place to buy something (that's not what I'm asking for).  It's just that I don't know what to be buying in the first place.  I've done all the research I can, I've tried every search I can, searched through all the product info, and I'm still coming up with that link I provided being the only things that appear to be options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to buy an adapter and a large set of normal drills.

Another solution is to look for hex-shank drill sets

---

### Bosch Uneo

#### Adapter

[image]

> **Bosch 2608572075 1/4" 1-10mm Keyless Chuck Adaptor (Suitable for UNEO)**
>
> Suitable for use in a cordless screwdriver and drills with forward / reverse function. Can also be used with the Bosch UNEO drill to allow the use of standard shank drill bits.
>
> Mount : 1/4"
> Capacity : 1mm - 10mm

This seems to be available from a variety of retailers.

#### Hex-drive

Bosch's list of compatible accessories for the Uneo includes their 43-piece X-Line drill set which all have standard hex-drive shanks. This suggests you could use any hex-drive drill set from any manufacturer.

[image]

---

### Ikea FIXA

I think Ikea's FIXA version of the Uneo comes with such an adapter.

[image]

Comment: The only adapter I've found is for the SDS-Plus, not the SDS-Quick, which I don't think is compatible: https://www.boschtools.com/us/en/boschtools-ocs/hammer-hammer-drill-attachments-ha3jaw-35427-p/

Comment: @solidcell - see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm not going to buy another drill again just to get the adapter.

Comment: Ah, now I see the other part of your edit isn't about the one that comes from the IKEA set.  Thanks :)

Comment: @solidcell, you can buy the adapter separately from any Bosch retailer. The FIXA info is for future readers who stumble on this in search results (and to demonstrate that such adapters are normal and useful)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks again. Yea hopefully it helps someone else too.